# How many 虾 are 三只半虾？

Tags: number

I was reading about [《三只半虾》](http://hsk2020.com/text?t=486) 齐白石， 以画虾享誉画坛。

三只虾：3 prawns

半虾：half a prawn

一半只虾： half a prawn

三只半虾：3 and 1 half prawns?? or 3 half prawns = 1 and 1 half prawns??

*三半只虾？？？= ？

Comment: [Reference here](http://hsk2020.com/text?t=486)

Answer (score 3):

> 三只虾：3 prawns

good

> 半虾：half a prawn

Wrong. It should be 半只虾

> 一半只虾： half a prawn

Wrong. See above.

> 三只半虾：3 and 1 half prawns?? or 3 half prawns = 1 and 1 half prawns??

Three and a half prawns.

Chinese grammar wiki has a page about [Expressing half with ban](https://resources.allsetlearning.com/chinese/grammar/Expressing_%22half%22_with_%22ban%22).

The structure "Number + Measure Word + 半 + Noun" means "*Number* and a half *nouns*"

Answer (score 2):

三只半 = 三只 + 半只 = 3.5只

三半只虾 Is wrong, but you can say 三个半只虾, which means there are 3 pieces, and each piece is a half prawn. It doesn't equal to 1.5 只虾 (一只半虾), because there is not a complete one.

Answer (score 1):

3.5只。

‘半’ following a measure word means 'and a half' (e.g. 两年半： two years and a half; 三只半虾：three prawns and a half), while followed by a mearsure word it means 'half a' (e.g. 半只虾： half a prawn).

Comment: 两年半 doesn't have any measure word

Comment: 两年半 is actually a shorter form of 两年半（时间）and the latter is quite common in both written and spoken language (e.g 这个项目花了我两年半时间。It took me 2 years to finish the project.). So here 年 is better to be interpreted as a measure word - it specifies the time is measured by 'year', instead of 'day/week' etc, and would make more sense in the general 'number + measure word + noun' framework in Chinese.